# Simple iOS Bluetooth Data Transmission Using Unity

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, bluetooth

Is there any simple (or even not so simple) way to transmit just small amounts of data (some small strings and the occasional number) between 2 iOS devices using Unity? I know there are some assets on the Asset Store, but those are upwards or $50 and far overkill. Or is there a good tutorial for this that I can follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> those are upwards or $50

No, they are not. Here is a [Bluetooth](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/26661) plugin for **Android** and **iOS** for $10.

The rule goes like:

If you are one person, use that. You will save yourself time. If you are working for a company, you should make your own plugin.

> is there a good tutorial for this that I can follow?

If you decide to make your own Bluetooth plugin, you must first learn Java. Make a simple Android Java Bluetooth program and test it on your Android device. If it works, then you can then simply convert it into a plugin by seperating the code into functions such as `bluetoothInit()`, `bluetoothConnect()`, `bluetoothSend()`, `bluetoothReceive()`, `bluetoothDisconnect()`, `bluetoothClose()`. Then compile it into a plugin (**jar** or **aar**) file. You can now call the functions from Unity C#.

Learn [Android Bluetooth API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html).

Links on how to call Java functions from C# in Unity. I suggest you follow the first link.

http://www.what-could-possibly-go-wrong.com/creating-a-native-android-plugin-for-unity3d/

http://www.thegamecontriver.com/2015/04/android-plugin-unity-android-studio.html

https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/06/creating-an-android-java-plugin-for-unity3d/

**EDIT:**

For **iOS**, you need to learn Objective-C. Learn iOS Bluetooth API then make a plugin.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-7-sdk-core-bluetooth-practical-lesson--mobile-20741

Comment: And what about for iOS?

Comment: @dsiegler19 I just realized that this question is for iOS. I edited it and provided info about iOS too. I will admit that the iOS version is harder than Android. I suggest you go with the already made plugin. You will save yourself time.

Comment: @Programmer does this Unity Asset for both Android and iOS work crossplatform, so that messages from Andriod to IOS and back can be sent?